# Android: Retrieving Password via registered Email on My Server

Tags: android, web-services, password-retrieval

i am working on retrieving password to the user when he submits his mail id that he registered on my server. I need to check whether he entered correct registered id and give him response by sending password to his corresponding mail and set dialog as password sent to your mail or if he entered wrong mail id i have to show mail id not registered... Any Idea? This is my code...

```
             package com.soap;
             import java.util.regex.Matcher;
             import java.util.regex.Pattern;
             import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
             import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
             import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
             import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
             import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
             import android.app.Activity;
             import android.app.Dialog;
             import android.app.ProgressDialog;
            import android.os.Bundle;
          import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
           import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
           import android.widget.Button;
          import android.widget.EditText 

       public class Register extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

// static Spinner operator = null;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "......";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "......";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "......";
private static final String URL = "My site";
private static final String TAG = "HELLO";

Thread t;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.forgotpasswordpage);
    Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fpwdsubmit);

    signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0: {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait while connecting...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }
    }
    return null;
}

public void register() {
    Log.v(TAG, "Trying to Login");
    EditText etxt_user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fpedtext);
    String email_id = etxt_user.getText().toString();
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("Email", email_id);
     Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN =Pattern.compile(
             "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
             "\\@" +
             "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
             "(" +
             "\\." +
             "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
             ")+");
     Matcher matcher = EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email_id);
     if(matcher.matches()){
      Log.v(TAG, "Your email id is valid ="+email_id);
    //  System.out.println("Your email id is valid ="+email);
     }
     else{
   //  System.out.println("enter valid email id");
      Log.v(TAG, "enter valid email id" );
     }
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        aht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"); 
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you expect to see the code how to do that or what?

Comment: @denis.solonenko i will post my code ... if i got response as -1 i have to show dialog as enter valid email...if i got response as 1 i need to show dialog as password has been sent...plz share your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Fallow these step then you got your answer.

1-: Parse your response ans store in a local variable like int resTemp=0;

2-:Use the given blow code accordingly.

```
    if(resTemp==1)
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder successfullyLogin = new Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            successfullyLogin.setCancelable(false);
                            successfullyLogin.setMessage("Successfully Login !");
                            successfullyLogin.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                                {
                                    finish();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainMenuActivity.class));
                                }
                            });
                            successfullyLogin.show();


                        }
   else if(resTemp==-1){

                            AlertDialog.Builder unsuccessfullyLogin = new Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            unsuccessfullyLogin.setCancelable(false);
                            unsuccessfullyLogin.setMessage("Invalid Username or Password !");
                            unsuccessfullyLogin.setPositiveButton("TryAgain",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                                {
                                    etLoginUserName.setText("");
                                    etLoginPassword.setText("");
                                    etLoginUserName.requestFocus();
                                }
                            });
                            unsuccessfullyLogin.setNeutralButton("Forgot Password",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                            {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                                {

                                }
                            });

                            unsuccessfullyLogin.show();

                        }
```

I hope it is useful to you.

Comment: Hai before doing this if conditions... i need to know how to parse my result and declare as a variable....

Comment: Look my another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055092/how-to-parse-xml-in-android/6055171#6055171 for parsing xml file

Comment: i tried by declaring the results but i am not sure that is correct...plz tell how to parse the result and declare as a variable...